# Why is my converter (based on ListView.ItemsSource) not being called?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a small WPF application in which I have a list of files. Below the list of files I have an "Upload" button. I would like the text in the upload button to display "Upload x files" where x is the number of items in the list.

I am using a converter which takes the ItemsSource property as input and returns the string, however if I add or remove items from the listview (ie. it's underlying collection) the converter on the button binding is not called.

What am I doing incorrectly?

I have the base class:

```
public class FileItem : INotifyPropertyChanged { ... }
```

And an ObservableCollection:

```
public class Files : ObservableCollection<FileItem> {}
```

An I assign the collection to the ListView.

```
lvw_FileList.ItemsSource = new Files();
```

The ListView has it's ItemSource property bound.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvw_FileList" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
...
</ListView>
```

The button which text content needs a converter based on the ListView.ItemsSource.

```
<Button Content="{Binding ElementName=lvw_FileList, Path=ItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource UpdateButtonConverter}}" x:Name="btn_Upload" />
```

Comment: The binding of the `ListView.ItemsSource` is useless, you overwrite it with your assignment in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings only listen to [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) and not [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged.aspx) notifications. If you need to run the conversion whenever the collection changes consider a `MultiBinding` to both the collection and its `Count` property. The count change will trigger a reevaluation and the collection value can be used in the converter.